# how to filter the row with max value(more than 1) in multiple columns by data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this:

```
set.seed(1)    
dt <- data.frame(names = sample(letters[1:3],15,replace = T),
                 v1 = c(1:10,11,11,3:5),
                 v2 = c(32,32,13:1))
```

I want to filter the rows with max v1 and v2 by names, which works with the code below:

```
setDT(dt)[,.SD[v1 == max(v1)],by = names][,.SD[v2 == max(v2)],by = names]
```

but the code is a bit longer than I want. Then I tried this:

```
setDT(dt)[,.SD[v1 == max(v1) & v2 == max(v2)],by = names]
```

it throws "Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: names,v1,v2." I don't know why,anyone could enlighten me ?

Comment: This is because the row with max value isn't the same for both the cols. The 1st code works due to sequential subsetting by returning the max value in the subset. The 2nd code returns no matched rows due to `&`. Check `which(dt$v1 == max(dt$v1))` and `which(dt$v2 == max(dt$v2))` to identify the rows with max values. Try changing from `&` to `|` to get the results.

Comment: @KarthikArumugham is right. Your way to do it is good. If you really want to do it in one step try `dt[,.SD[v1==max(v1) & v2==max(v2*(v1==max(v1)))],by=names]`.

Comment: @KarthikArumugham thanks your explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also make this compact with

```
setDT(dt)[order(names, -v2),  head(.SD[v1==max(v1)], 1), by = names]
#   names v1 v2
#1:     a 11  5
#2:     b  9  7
#3:     c  7  9
```

---

Or as @Frank mentioned, we can order by both 'v1' and 'v2' and get the first element with `unique`

```
unique(setDT(dt)[order(-v1, -v2)], by="names")
```

Comment: @Frank Yes, that is nice.  I should have `order`ed by both